# Compare data frame multiple columns with row in R

Tags: r

I have data frame with multiple columns and rows. I want to compare column number 7 rows to the header of columns 1,2,4 and 5 and if it matches then print the sequence present in that column as new column. The common pattern between the columns and rows is `.x` and `.y`

My data frame looks like this

```
    F_20TP53_Seq.x  F_30TP53_Seq.x  R_20TP53_Seq.x  F_20TP53_Seq.y  F_30TP53_Seq.y  R_20TP53_Seq.y  Name_of_F_TP53
    CACTGT  CAAAGT  CATAGT  AATGTTG CACAGT  CAAAGT  F_20TP53_Max_score.y
    CACAGT  CACTGT  CACAGT  CCAAGG  CATAGT  CACTGT  F_30TP53_Max_score.y
    CATAGT  AATGTTG CACAG   GCCAGG  CACAGT  CACTGT  F_20TP53_Max_score.x
    CACAGT  CCAAGG  CACCAT  CAAAGT  CACAG   CACAGT  F_30TP53_Max_score.x
    CACTGT  CACAGT  CCAAGG  CACTGT  CACCAT  CATAGT  F_30TP53_Max_score.y
```

And my expected output is like this

```
    F_20TP53_Seq.x  F_30TP53_Seq.x  R_20TP53_Seq.x  F_20TP53_Seq.y  F_30TP53_Seq.y  R_20TP53_Seq.y  Name_of_F_TP53  F_20TP53_Seq.x  F_30TP53_Seq.x  F_20TP53_Seq.y  F_30TP53_Seq.y
    CACTGT  CAAAGT  CATAGT  AATGTTG CACAGT  CAAAGT  F_20TP53_Max_score.y    NA  NA  AATGTTG CACAGT
    CACAGT  CACTGT  CACAGT  CCAAGG  CATAGT  CACTGT  F_30TP53_Max_score.y    NA  NA  CCAAGG  CATAGT
    CATAGT  AATGTTG CACAG   GCCAGG  CACAGT  CACTGT  F_20TP53_Max_score.x    CATAGT  AATGTTG NA  NA
    CACAGT  CCAAGG  CACCAT  CAAAGT  CACAG   CACAGT  F_30TP53_Max_score.x    CACAGT  CCAAGG  NA  NA
    CACTGT  CACAGT  CCAAGG  CACTGT  CACCAT  CATAGT  F_30TP53_Max_score.y    NA  NA  CACTGT  CACCAT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `stringr` package below to extract a logical vector as to whether or not there is a match in the target column

```
library(stringr)

cbind(
  d,
  setNames(
    lapply(c(1,2,4,5), function(x) {
      key = paste0(str_extract(colnames(d)[x],"x|y"),"$")
      k <- str_detect(d$Name_of_F_TP53,key)
      sapply(seq_along(k),function(l) ifelse(k[l],d[l,x],NA))
    }), colnames(d)[c(1,2,4,5)])
)
```

Output:

```
  F_20TP53_Seq.x F_30TP53_Seq.x R_20TP53_Seq.x F_20TP53_Seq.y F_30TP53_Seq.y R_20TP53_Seq.y         Name_of_F_TP53
1         CACTGT         CAAAGT         CATAGT        AATGTTG         CACAGT         CAAAGT   F_20TP53_Max_score.y
2         CACAGT         CACTGT         CACAGT         CCAAGG         CATAGT         CACTGT   F_30TP53_Max_score.y
3         CATAGT        AATGTTG          CACAG         GCCAGG         CACAGT         CACTGT   F_20TP53_Max_score.x
4         CACAGT         CCAAGG         CACCAT         CAAAGT          CACAG         CACAGT   F_30TP53_Max_score.x
5         CACTGT         CACAGT         CCAAGG         CACTGT         CACCAT         CATAGT   F_30TP53_Max_score.y
  F_20TP53_Seq.x F_30TP53_Seq.x F_20TP53_Seq.y F_30TP53_Seq.y
1           <NA>           <NA>        AATGTTG         CACAGT
2           <NA>           <NA>         CCAAGG         CATAGT
3         CATAGT        AATGTTG           <NA>           <NA>
4         CACAGT         CCAAGG           <NA>           <NA>
5           <NA>           <NA>         CACTGT         CACCAT
```

Comment: @lantang The above code generates output with multiple columns after `Name_of_F_TP53` column. If rows in `Name_of_F_TP53` column matches with column number `1,2,4 and 5 `then print the matching sequences from these four columns into another four columns.  And this matching should be on the basis of .`x and .y` letter from  `Name_of_F_TP53` to columns 1,2,4 and 5. If it does not match then print `NA`, as i showed in the expected output. ( i am not getting the expected output from the above code)

Comment: Got it. sorry, I did not understand until I saw your desired output. I will edit answer now.